# Enterprise library 4 validation using config file

Tags: xml, visual-studio, validation, enterprise-library

I was wondering, how can I validate string field (length) if it's not required and can be null? How can i skip validation if my string is null? My Current validation is this, but it's not 'null friendly':

```
            <validator lowerBound="0" lowerBoundType="Ignore" upperBound="150"
          upperBoundType="Inclusive" negated="false" messageTemplate=""
          messageTemplateResourceName="my_message"
          messageTemplateResourceType="Project.Messages, Project, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
          tag="" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.StringLengthValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=11222ff322r645e"
          name="String Length Validator" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to use a OrCompositeValidator.

Here is one that allows null or a value between 1 and 100.
But should give you the idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="validation" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <validation>
        <type name="ValidationTest.Data" defaultRuleset="" assemblyName="ConsoleApplication4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
            <ruleset name="RuleSet1">
                <properties>
                    <property name="MyProperty">
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.OrCompositeValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            name="Or Composite Validator" />
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.NotNullValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            negated="true" name="Not Null Validator" />
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RangeValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            culture="en-US" lowerBound="1" lowerBoundType="Inclusive"
                            upperBound="100" name="Range Validator" />
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </ruleset>
        </type>
    </validation>
</configuration>
```